# cut hls files in to many small ".ts" files or keep one big ".ts" file. which is better?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to stream my videos using HLS bytes range HTTP requests.

FFmpeg has an option to keep all the ts file to one single large ".ts" file.

Any pros and cons of split the ts files or keep a big ts file?

Is a big ts file make the request slower? because of HDD fseek is slow?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the split variant because

- better performance (lower CPU load) of the webserver (no need to seek always within the same file; just deliver the whole, small, file)
- better support of the clients (some, mostly older clients or SmartTVs, have issues with the big file (during seeking or at the video beginning; some of them also try to download the whole file first for any reason before starting playback))
- small files can be better cached (within your webserver or through a CDN; most CDNs have a size limit and some others don't caching partial files)

I don't find on the other side any relevant benefits for the large file variant.

- Maybe faster cleanup, because only one file instead of a whole folder must be deleted

Comment: large files can also be cached perfectly with nginx slice module.
you can refer to  https://www.nginx.com/blog/smart-efficient-byte-range-caching-nginx/

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg has -hls_time option to set length of *.ts files. Apple suggest time of 6 seconds. In our case we have set it to 30 seconds (-hls_time 30), which results in larger size but smaller number of *.ts files, which is more practical for uploading ,storing and retrieving to/from object storage.